# R package 'spatstat': installation problems

Tags: r, spatstat

The installation of the 'spatstat' package works fine. But when I load the package with `>library(spatstat)` I get the following response:

> Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
>         es gibt kein Paket namens ‘goftest'

In addition: Warning message:

> Paket ‘spatstat’ wurde unter R Version 3.0.3 erstellt
>
> Error: Laden von Paket oder Namensraum für ‘spatstat’ fehlgeschlagen

translated to English:

> Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
>         package ‘goftest' does not exist

In addition: Warning message:

> Paket ‘spatstat’ has been created under R Version 3.0.3
>
> Error: Loading of package and namespace for ‘spatstat’ failed

Any ideas what's wrong? I re-installed it numerous times and still get the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please state your operating system (Windows/Linux/OSX...) As well as your version of R and how you installed spatstat (from source/binary). It appears you don't have the package `goftest` installed. Did you try to install it?

```
install.packages("goftest")
```

Note that you need R version 3.1.1 or higher to run the latest version of `spatstat` (and `goftest` needs 3.1 or higher).

Comment: The old R-version was the problem - shame on me.

Comment: Nothing to be ashamed of. Thanks for actually following up and accepting the answer. Remember to state your `sessionInfo()` when you ask R questions of this type; that would have made it even easier to point to the problem.

Comment: Okay, good to know! Thank you again for your quick and helpful response.